# I can't install mobgodb versions newer than 3.0.1 on yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, composer-php

For some reason composer can't install mongodb versions newer than 3.0.1
Gives an error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- Root composer.json requires yiisoft/yii2-mongodb ^3.6, found yiisoft/yii2-mongodb[dev-master, 2.0.0-beta, ..., 2.1.x-dev (alias of dev-master), 3.0.0, 3.0.1] but it does not match the constraint.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific version

I tried to install the drivers. Where to extract the file php_mongodb.dll .
In the php.ini file, I wrote "extension=php_mongodb.dll ", because if you write "extension=php_mongo.dll ", then composer will give an error:

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mongo.dll' (tried: d:/openserver/modules/php/PHP_8.1/ext\php_mongo.dll (╨Э╨╡ ╨╜╨░╨╣╨┤╨╡╨╜ ╤Г
╨║╨░╨╖╨░╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨╝╨╛╨┤╤Г╨╗╤М), d:/openserver/modules/php/PHP_8.1/ext\php_php_mongo.dll.dll (╨Э╨╡ ╨╜╨░╨╣╨┤╨╡╨╜ ╤Г╨║╨░╨╖╨░╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨╝╨╛╨┤╤Г╨╗╤М)) in Unknown on line 0.